# Android | Apache License в XML

Tags: android, apache

Что за бред? Вчера построил себе нормальный xml, никаких сторонних пакетов не использовал, только то, что было предварительно установлено в AS, а сегодня утром просыпаюсь и меня встречает это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даже все что под комментарием создано - не мое.

Comment: В смысле - это вообще не ваш код? Было у меня один раз, что студия путала файлы - открывала даже какой-то бинарный бред вместо нужных. Попробуйте сбросить кеш и переоткрыть проект.

Comment: Код вообще не мой, но файл открыл точно нужный. Мне повезло, то что меня ударило в голову залезть в папку с проектом и открыть файл через блокнот, там был мой код и я его скопировал. А после того как нажал одну кнопку в "не моем" xml, то код и в блокноте изменился на этот. Сейчас все хорошо, но мне это не понравилось, первый раз такое. Еще и присутствие какой-то лицензии напугало

Comment: Вот после подобных приколов вырабатывается привычка использовать git или другие системы контроля версий и сохранять коммиты на как можно чаще :) А лицензия APL2.0 не страшная - она обязывает только указать коприрайт. Это содержимое какого-то лейаута из фреймворка или библиотек поддержки, поэтому на нём копирайт AOSP